# How do I implement @POST in Retrofit and save oAuth2 token?

Tags: rest, kotlin, google-oauth, retrofit2

I'm using Kotlin and Retrofit2

**What I would want to do:**

I would want to get an access token and save it somewhere so I could use it later. How implementation should look like using Retrofit2? Especially "@POST" operation? I have to provide login, password, client secret and client id in order do get oAuth2 token. And what should I do after declaring @POST operation, where should I initialize this and where to save this token.

Comment: access token's expire after an hour.   Why would you want to bother storing it?  You must used oauth2 to request consent of the user. You can not pass their login and password.

Comment: I would want to save it, because in order to get data from API I guess I have to add access token to the header of GET operation if I am not mistaken. In order to get this token as per documentation I need to include login, password, clientid and client secret(it has been provided to me before,  I just need to wrap this data in POST operation and save the token I guess.

Comment: Access tokens are used to gain access to the API yes. It is sent as an authorization header on all your requests.  However access tokens are short lived and expire after an hour.   You would need to request offline access and get a refresh token.  Store the refresh token it will allow you to request a new access token when it has expired.

Comment: I have a video which explains how Oauth2 works.  [Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w) it uses curl to show how it works step by step.   I think you may be a little confused as to how Oauth2 works.